# Nhibernate join tables by multiple columns

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following problem with an NHibernate query.

one table

```
LearnerDocuments :
    LearnerNumber
    CandidateNumber
    ....
```

other table

```
LearnerRegistration :
    LearnerId
    LearnerNumber
    ....
```

the last one

```
Learner : 
    LearnerId 
    LearnerName 
    ....
```

The relation between `LearnerDocuments` and and `LearnerRegistration` doesn't exist.

How can I write a query that gets all `LearnerRegistration` which have `LearnerDocuments`?

Comment: Can you please tell whcih mapping technology you are using ? Like automapping or hbm or fluent

Comment: You'll need to define the relation/mapping to `join` the table. NH can't do adhoc joins. However you could do an `exists` clause. Which do you want?

Comment: the problem was solved using  Projections.Exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 criteria.CreateCriteria(typeof(LearnerRegistration), "av")
                    ......

                    .Add(Restrictions.IsNotNull("RegistrationNumber"))                    
                    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("l.Id", detachedCriteria))

                 ;


            var candidate = DetachedCriteria.For<LearnerDocuments>("sd")
                        .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                        .Add(Projections.Property("sd.CandidateNumber"))
                        .Add(Projections.Property("sd.RegistrationNumber")))
                        .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("sd.CandidateNumber", "l.LearnerNumber") 
                        && Restrictions.EqProperty("sd.RegistrationNumber", "lr.RegistrationNumber")
                        );

            var proj = Projections.Conditional(Subqueries.Exists(candidate),Projections.Constant(true),Projections.Constant(false));
```